# Is there any difference between "be about" and "means"?

Tags: meaning

For example you can say:

> - True love **is about** wanting happiness for the person you love.
> - True love **means** wanting happiness for the person you love.

Is there any difference between two sentences semantically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that *means* establishes an equivalency.  It says that one thing is the same as the other:

> To run *means* to move quickly.

It provides a kind of definition for something that doesn't allow for other interpretations.

---

But *is about* just says that something only *includes* something else. It can also be about *other* things:

> The movie *is about* peace, love, and understanding.

It doesn't preclude the possibility of something else that wasn't mentioned. (It would if *is* ***only*** *about* were used.)

Both syntactically *and* semantically, these two example sentences would lose their meaning if they had the one word replaced by the other.

---

If we rephrased it, the first sentence could accommodate the other word:

> Running is about moving quickly.

That seems to say the same thing, but it does so in a narrow sense. Because it could also be about getting somewhere quickly or getting away from somewhere quickly.

Conversely, however, it would be unusual to hear:

> To run means to get somewhere quickly.

This statement isn't always true. Sometimes it's not about getting somewhere quickly, it's only about the activity itself. So, without qualification, we use *means* as a universal statement—in the same way that dictionaries provides definitions for words.

---

Sometimes they can be used in a mostly equivalent way, but there will be at least a subtle difference—if not something (syntax or semantics) that actually precludes one from being a replacement for the other.

Answer (score 2):

**about**  is normally used to refer to a subject or topic.

> That book is about dogs.

The book concerns itself with dogs.

When **about** is used to say what something *is*, to define it, the preposition refers to the scope or ambit of the actions that are essential to or emblematic of that thing.

> Helping around the house **is about** taking the garbage out, cleaning up the kitchen after you've made yourself a snack,  keeping things tidy, bringing in the mail, and things of that nature.

The verb **means** can be used in the same manner. It too can refer to the actions which are essential to or emblematic of the thing:

> Helping around the house **means** taking the garbage out, cleaning up the kitchen after you've made yourself a snack,  keeping things tidy, bringing in the mail, and things of that nature.

So in this context the two sentences are synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

While Jason Bassford's answer does not include any incorrect information, I think it fails to talk about this specific use of these two expressions, which is to declare some *fundamental aspect*, e.g.

> A good answer on ELL **means/is about** addressing the specific question asked

While there are other uses of both "means" and "is about", in this particular case they are functionally equivalent.  In both cases you declare some element that is of primary importance to the subject

Some examples:

> For me, traveling **means/is about** seeing something new and unexpected

i.e. novelty is *a fundamental reason* why I like to travel.

> Learning a new language sometimes **means/is about** learning to *think* in a different way.

i.e. in order to learn a new language, sometimes *you are required* to think in a different way.

> Freedom of speech **is not about/does not mean** freedom from the consequences of what you choose to say.

i.e. *it is important* to understand that the right to speak freely does not mean you can say anything you want without consequence.

There are other contexts in which these two expressions can mean different things, but in this context they are the same.